# CKComponentKit CollectionView issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, componentkit

I am currently experimenting with ComponentKit and I am having an issue. I want to use the CKCollectionView I created on a main view. When I had the CKCollectionView to its container in my MainView(which contains a ScrollView) I am having 2 issues. The first one, if I manually create the frame of the CollectionView, here what it gives me.(Blue square is the "UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView")

[image: UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView]

But, what I really want to do is set the frame using Masonry and constraints, allowing me to set the frame equal to its container (the yellow square). But when I do that, it FILLS the entire Blue rectangle height with empty cells, like in the picture below:

[image: Issue with Constraints]

So it seems like my actual cells (or Components) have a size of 647 and they are causing problems.But at this point I am lost and was wondering if anybody had a similar issue before :).

Here is my code:

The actual component that creates the cell:

```
@implementation SSOUpcomingAuctionComponent


+ (instancetype)newWithProduct:(Product *)product {

    SSOProductHeaderComponent *head = [SSOProductHeaderComponent newWithTitle:product.time];
    SSOProductPictureComponent *body = [SSOProductPictureComponent newWithImage:product.image];
    SSOProductShareComponent *footer = [SSOProductShareComponent newWithPrice:product.price];

    return [super newWithComponent:[CKInsetComponent newWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
                                                         component:[CKStackLayoutComponent newWithView:{
                                                             [UIView class], {
                                                                 { @selector(setBackgroundColor:), [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                                                 , { CKComponentViewAttribute::LayerAttribute(@selector(setCornerRadius:)), @6.0 }
                                                                 , { @selector(setClipsToBounds:), @YES }
                                                             }
                                                         } size:{}
                                                        style:{
                                                             .alignItems = CKStackLayoutAlignItemsCenter, .direction = CKStackLayoutDirectionVertical,
                                                             .spacing = 2
                                                         } children:{{
                                                                         head,
                                                                     },
                                                                     {body},
                                                                     {footer}}]]];
}

#pragma mark - ProviderMethod

@end
```

The CollectionViewController:

```
#import "UpcomingAuctionViewController.h"
#import "SSOUpcomingAuctionComponent.h"
#import <ComponentKit/ComponentKit.h>
#import "Product.h"
#import "ProductPages.h"
#import "ProductModelController.h"
#import <ChameleonFramework/Chameleon.h>
#import "Masonry.h"

@interface UpcomingAuctionViewController () <CKComponentProvider, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@end

@implementation UpcomingAuctionViewController {
    CKCollectionViewDataSource *_dataSource;
    CKComponentFlexibleSizeRangeProvider *_sizeRangeProvider;
    ProductModelController *_productModelController;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout {
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]) {
        _sizeRangeProvider = [CKComponentFlexibleSizeRangeProvider providerWithFlexibility:CKComponentSizeRangeFlexibleWidth];
        _productModelController = [[ProductModelController alloc] init];
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor flatWhiteColorDark];
//    [self.collectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)];
        [self.collectionView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
          make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
        }];
    [self.collectionView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

    // Creates and sets our dataSource to our CKCollectionViewDataSource, THE MAIN ACTOR/INFRASTRUCTURE that takes our MODEL, creates a COMPONENT STACKS then
    // transforms it into a VIEW HIERARCHY.
    _dataSource = [[CKCollectionViewDataSource alloc] initWithCollectionView:self.collectionView
                                                 supplementaryViewDataSource:nil
                                                           componentProvider:[self class]
                                                                     context:nil
                                                   cellConfigurationFunction:nil];

    // The following block of code adds a section at 0 and two items at 0 and 1.
    CKArrayControllerSections sections;
    // insert section 0
    sections.insert(0);
    [_dataSource enqueueChangeset:{
        sections, {}
    } constrainedSize:{}];
    [self enqueueProductPages:[_productModelController fetchNewUpcomingProductsWithCount:14]];
}

- (void)enqueueProductPages:(ProductPages *)productPage {

    NSArray *products = productPage.products;
    NSInteger position = productPage.position;

    CKArrayControllerInputItems items;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < products.count; i++) {
        items.insert([NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:position + i inSection:0], products[i]);
    }
    [_dataSource enqueueChangeset:{
        {}
        , items
    } constrainedSize:[_sizeRangeProvider sizeRangeForBoundingSize:self.collectionView.bounds.size]];
}

#pragma mark - CKComponentProvider

// Method that our componentProvider class NEED to implement
+ (CKComponent *)componentForModel:(Product *)product context:(Product *)context {
    return [SSOUpcomingAuctionComponent newWithProduct:product];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowlayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [_dataSource sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [_dataSource announceWillAppearForItemInCell:cell];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [_dataSource announceDidDisappearForItemInCell:cell];
}
```

And finally the mainViewController:

```
/**
 *  Initialize upcoming auctions container controller
 */
- (void)initializeUpcomingAuctionsContainerView {

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:10];
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0);

    self.upcomingAuctionsVC = [[UpcomingAuctionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    [self addChildViewController:self.upcomingAuctionsVC];

    [self.bottomView addSubview:self.upcomingAuctionsVC.view];

    [self.upcomingAuctionsVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

@end
```

Thanks for the help everyone and have a great day.